# return iterator from std::set::insert() is const?

Tags: c++, stl

According to the C++ reference, set::insert is supposed to return pair where the iterator points to either the newly inserted element, or the existing element if such existed.

But I'm having a problem assigning to the iterator, as this simple examples shows:

```
int main() {
  set<int> set;
  *set.insert(5).first = 5;
  return 0;
}
```

I've tried G++ and Clang and neither works.

```
set.cc:7:24: error: read-only variable is not assignable
  *set.insert(5).first = 5;
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
```

I can't find anything in the documentation that indicates that the iterator should deference to a const object, and nothing in the type signature would indicate this either.  Can someone help me understand why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), both its associated `iterator` and `const_iterator` types are constant bidirectional iterators. The reason for this is because `std::set` is ordered. If you were to modify an element of the set though an iterator, you would be breaking that ordering.

Consider a `std::set` with ordered elements `{1, 4, 8}`. If you then did something like `*set.insert(5).first = 10;` (if it were allowed), first `5` would be inserted to get `{1, 4, 5, 8}` and then the inserted element would be set to `10` to get `{1, 4, 10, 8}`. The ordering invariant has now been broken.

Since you're inserting `5` with `insert(5)`, there's no reason to dereference the iterator and assign `5` to it.

Comment: Duh.  I should have thought of this.  Thanks.  In my real example, it wasn't an int, is was a more complex object that I wanted to change some state on.

Answer (score 5):

You can't modify a set's members in place. It's an ordered container. Its iterators are not assignable.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, set iterators refer to `const` types (see [set reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/)). If you think about it it makes sense, as a set stores its element ordered, and simply changing a certain element would most likely violate the ordering constraints.